# How do I use markdown to generate a PDF will full background-color/image bleed?

Tags: css, pdf-generation, markdown

I have a simple markdown document that has either a *background color* or *background image* defined in the stylesheet I'm using to render it.  When I export to PDF (using marked.app, mou.app, markdown pro, Multimarkdown Composer etC), I'd like that background to be full-bleed on the page with no margin or padding (i.e. no surrounding whitespace), much like something you'd create in illustrator.

Here is an [example](https://uploads.intercomcdn.com/i/o/761447/7cefb97570793c7adcb047ac/Intercom%2520on%2520Product%2520Management%2520%25281%2529.pdf). (Reference the cover page). This will be used solely for on-screen consumption so I'm not worried about printing.

Can anyone suggest how to do this or a mac app that can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "When I export to PDF". How are you doing this? The original version of Markdown outputs HTML, not PDF. Are you trying to do `.md` ⟶ `.html` ⟶ `.pdf`? If so, what are you using for the second conversion? There are other Markdown processors that support PDF output (e.g. [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)), but generally these also use an intermediate format (LaTeX in the case of Pandoc). Note that Markdown is *dramatically* less expressive than many other languages, and it may not do what you want by itself.

Comment: @Chris I've used apps like marked.app, mou.app, markdown pro, Multimarkdown Composer, Pandoc etc.